# Is it possible to reboot app without page refresh?

Tags: angular

I am wondering if it is possible reboot the app without page refresh? I want it to happen when user logs out, so that all the services get refreshed.

Thanks

Comment: I wouldn't do that. Just make everything that depends on the login-state subscribe to the login state and when login state changes make it reinitialize itself.

Comment: There is a way to get the `ComponentRef` for `AppComponent` from `bootstrap()`, destroy it on logout and call `bootstrap()` again but that's quite ugly.

Comment: I guess thats one of the alternative solutions. I  will keep the question open though, as the ability to refresh app without page refresh may be useful in some cases.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Its not working when the application is build using systemjs or webpack

Comment: Sorry, don't know about systemjs or webpack.